# Android : how to stream/play any music file on HTML page in android browser

Tags: android

There is one HTML page, streaming a music file and It's working on window but i need to run this html file on android.
also i need to control all the feature of music by javascript function e.g. play,pause,stop, **volume up & down**.

Can someone give me any idea?

Note : i am new to android but good hand in java. Just going through android tutorial and i came to know this feature can be done using `webview`. is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183102/possible-webview-oncreatewindow-to-make-popup-windowdialog-style-like-android) is an example quite close to the thing you're going to do...

```
public class MyJSInterface{
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
....
 public void play(String url){

    this.mp.setDataSource(url);
    this.mp.prepare();
    this.mp.start();    

//  AlterDialog etc.

 }

 public void stop(){

    this.mp.stop();        

 }

....

}


HTML from your website:
function _play(url){
  window.myappname.play(url);
}
function _stop(url){
  window.myappname.stop();
}
```

thing you may need 
[Android Media](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear from the post if its a requirement that you have to play it on a html page or you just want to play the .mp3 file linked from some online page.

However, You can look at [this Streaming Audio tutorial](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/) as an initial reference. The MediaPlayer API would be your goto place in android for anything to do with Audio/ Video. WebView is mainly for embedding a browser view within your android App.