# how to customize popwindow in webview

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-webview

i have developed web applictaion in android here i need to show the pop inside the webview,
i tried in many way when i using window.open means it open on the same webview or it can load in browser.

i have done the following settings

```
WebSettings settings = Browser.getSettings();  
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        Browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        Browser.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

but i want show the poplike this do any idea about how to show the popup in side the webview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  ....
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(), "myappname");
  webView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com/"); // or some local asset
  ....
}

public class MyJSInterface{

....
 public void popup(){

//  AlterDialog etc.

 }
....

}


HTML from your website:

window.onload = function(){
   window.myappname.popup();
}
```

OR

Use javascript interface. Combine javascript with java and make custom dialog in java At first, enable javascript

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
On second, you need to add javascript interface

wv.addJavascriptInterface(new DemoJavaScriptInterface(), "js");
And third, load url;

webview.loadUrl("javascript:javascript function name here");
Here is some code for you, hope this can help https://github.com/scottagarman/Android-JavaScript-Interface-Example

Reference : [possible WebView OnCreateWindow to make popup window(Dialog style)? like android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183102/possible-webview-oncreatewindow-to-make-popup-windowdialog-style-like-android)